# Styles are not getting overriten in the styled component in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am new to the reac, Here I am using the material UI .

I have designed following styled component.

```
const StyledDefaultText = styled(Typography)<ISortBySelector>(({ fontSize }) => ({
  fontSize: fontSize ? fontSize : '12px',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  letterSpacing: fontSize ? '0.14px' : '0.09px',
  color: '#000000'
}))
```

Now, Here I have added this styles still this component loads with the default styles which are there for the `typography`. It does not apply the styles which are there in the style component.
Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: ```Typography``` is your own component? Can you post its source code?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that your styles are loaded before the styles of the material-ui library (last one wins). You can fix it like this:

```
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

<StylesProvider injectFirst>
  {/* Your component tree.
      Now, you can override Material-UI's styles. */}
</StylesProvider>
```

See: https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#controlling-priority-%EF%B8%8F-3